# Prepare HTTP/2 header for gRPC response in PHP

Tags: php, http-headers, protocol-buffers, grpc

I managed to write a config file for Nginx server and now I can receive rpc calls in PHP. I also used a library to provide HTTP/2 responses in PHP. But I am still missing a method to prepare the HTTP/2 header in a way that the gRPC client understands it.

My question is how to prepare gRPC HTTP/2 response header manually?

Answer (score 0):

In the client side, you can try see if headers are in the metadata. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/php/lib/Grpc/UnaryCall.php#L77